# Restore missed git commit on remote

Tags: git

Please, help. I made a mistake:

I move branch from commit `a` to commit `b`.

And now commit `a` is missed or detached.

When I'm trying:

set tag on gitlab on commit `a`

or

`git checkout a && git checkout -b branch-name && git push origin branch-name` on local mashine

I get error

`remote: fatal: ambiguous argument '1fcdaca7723d5939178c2557254c124aee30ec2d~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
remote: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
remote: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have the commit locally, you can simply create a new branch referencing it:

```
git checkout -b mybranch 1fcdaca7723d5939178c2557254c124aee30ec2d
```

And now you can push that branch to gitlab or wherever.